# Gatsby: Define static query in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

So in a page, you can define a query as an object in the javascript and it is automatically passed to the component as the `data` prop.

In components, that doesn't happen, and the examples I've seen show the query defined declaratively as part of the markup, then handed into a render method.  I really don't like that at all.

What is the gatsby way to define a graphql query in the JS of a component and then consume it in that component.

For example:

```
  <Img fixed={data.logo.childImageSharp.fixed} />
```

This is a gatsby image using the graphql data object.  But that object is only available on a page, not a component.  (Right now I'm passing the data prop into the component from the page, but that ain't what I want)

Comment: Can you show where you want to use that query?

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [useStaticQuery](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/use-static-query/) in the docs.

```
import React from "react"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"
export default () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query HeaderQuery {
      site {
        siteMetadata {
          title
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  return (
    <header>
      <h1>{data.site.siteMetadata.title}</h1>
    </header>
  )
}`
```